# core dump files batch processing (Windows)

Tags: windows, crash, batch-processing, windbg, minidump

I have many core dumpe (or minidump) files from customer (.dmp)
I can open each in MS Visual Studio and see the callstack.
I can do it also with WinDBG.
But since there are many of them and I want to categorize the crashes.
Is there a way to do batch processing that will get a list of .dmp files as input and give a list of .txt files with the callstack?

I tried WinDBG with commandline, but couldn't see how to create a command that takes .dmp file as input and prints the callstack as output (or save it in text file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
for %d in (*.dmp) do C:\fullpath\cdb.exe -c ".logopen %d.log; .exr -1; k; .logclose; q" -z %d
```

works for me most of the time.

- `for %d in (*.dmp) do` is there to process all DMP files
- `C:\fullpath\cdb.exe` runs the command line version of WinDbg
- `-c "..."` passes a command to CDB
- `-z %d` opens the dump file

As for the commands:

- `.logopen %d.log;` makes sure you save the output to different files (%d is replaced by the command line, not by WinDbg)
- `.exr -1;` gives you the exception information (since you typically want to sort on exception type)
- `k;` gives you the call stack
- `.logclose;` closes the output file
- `q` makes sure that WinDbg terminates and you're not stuck at some prompt

Comment: Thanks, Thomas!
- I added the analyze command: 
!analyze -v
- Added symbol path
set _NT_ALT_SYMBOL_PATH=c:\...